# Getting error: Invalid number['"] the row will be skipped

Tags: informatica, sqldatatypes, informatica-powercenter, invalid-characters, flatfilereader

We have one mapping source as flatfile and target as oracle table. Source file comma delimited file. In some rows we use to get ' or " enclosed values. We set optional quotes as double in source definition. The session is running fine in 10.2 informatica but it is failing in 10.4 informatica version stating the error: Row[rownumber].field[column name]: Invalid number:['"]. The row will be skipped. The column specified here is int datatype. If run same job using same file it is working in 10.2 informatica. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Run it in verbose mode to see what exactly is the issue. I think some non numeric data is coming and infa cant process it.  practice is to change all columns to a string datatype and then convert them next expression transformation.

Comment: We have added MatchQuotesPastEndOfLine=Yes and its worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: i know it resolved your issue but i feel like the solution form Maciejg is better.

Answer (score 1):

Read all data as strings, avoid implicit conversions. Any conversions shall be taken care of explicitely, in this case use `TO_INTEGER` function as described in [the documentation](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/data-services/10-1/transformation-language-reference/functions/to_integer.html). This will make capturing the error easier.

My guess is some trimming might be needed, or you'd need to remove the quotes.